# Eclipse JSF Server issue 'the file "" could not be found'

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, jsf-2.2

I am encountering a problem in which upon selecting an xhtml file from my project and selecting run on server (apache tomcat) 
I get the following error 'The file "http://localhost:8080/projectname/faces/index.xhtml" could not be found.

I tried following an example, to make sure I was doing things correctly (setup, creating files correctly), example site:

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fgettingstarted%2Ftutorial%2FJSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html

However it returns similar error only with instead of index as above it is login.

Hope this is enough information, I can supply more info such configuration details as well as images if they are needed. I hope someone has had this exact same problem!

Thanks!

Comment: Is your project name `projectname`? The default context root is the name of your project, unless you explicitly set it. The url you're searching is assumes `projectname` is the context root

Comment: That is just a placeholder I put, the actual name is experiment. However, the url that is being used is with the correct project name.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by deleting my eclipse files, and other associated files. Then re-installing them. This fixed the error. I am sure there is a better way of doing this (I hope so anyway) but this will work.